# Get data from MS access accdb file cache

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a database, data tables are linked lists from SharePoint server, while front-end is MS Access.
I created weekly backup of the access file (it's an .accdb file) by simply compying it.
Now I need some data from an old backup because the data has been modified on the SharePoint list. (I have a daily backup on the sharepoint site, too, but all the backups are deleted after 7 days and the data I need was modified a month ago.)

Well, I've read in some article that the MS Acess .accdb file still contains the cached data from the linked lists. And indeed: the size of my file is getting bigger every week as the amount of data is getting bigger on the sharepoint lists.

My plan is to open one of my backup files in MS Access while my computer is offline (in order to avoid the cache being updated from sharepoint lists) and somehow read the needed information from the cached tables but till now I got no success, MS access always complains for connection to the linked lists.

Is there any way to see the content of the list while being offline? Based on the size of the file the data must definitely be there.

Comment: You cannot suggest if the data is there from size. For example in company I work, I splitted accdb to front end and back end. Everyone uses only front end and after like month it has something around 200MB (on release it was 5MB), so you always have to compress and repair it.

Comment: @HynekBernard [Preventing corruption](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html)! Your file is 20 times larger than should be because it is corrupting.  You should have a front-end on each computer.

Comment: Isn't that because front end caching the data?

Comment: @marlan Personally, I'd never use access for this and if I had to, I would place front-end on each computer. And then there is my boss who needs everything placed on shared disk and run everything from it. There is no way I can place it on each computer, but it is not my responsibility anymore.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but can you link to it form another accdb? At what point does Access tell you it wants to be connected to SP? Can you make a view off the table? Can you connect via ADO/DAO and extract the data?

Comment: Immediately once I open the file.
What does "ADO/DAO" mean?